# If TextBox1.Text found in A:A, add TextBox2.Text to later cell in that row

Tags: vba

I have a UserForm for entering translations. There are TextBoxes for Title (txtTitle), Text to Translate (txtToTranslate) and Translated Text (txtTranslation) and a ComboBox to select language (cboLanguage).

The code currently creates a new row of data each time the user clicks submit.
I would like to modify the functionality as follows:

1 Clicking Submit, check if txtTitle already exists in A:A

2a If txtTitle does not exist, create new row (current functionality)

2b If txtTitle exists, add txtTranslation to the row with the txtTitle, rather than "NextRow"

```
    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range

    FindString = "*" & txtTitle

    If Trim(FindString) & "*" <> "" Then
        With Sheets("output").Range("A:A")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                ????                        
            Else
                Sheets("output").Activate
                NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
                    Cells(NextRow, 1) = txtTitle.Text
                    Cells(NextRow, 2) = txtToTranslate.Text                      
                        If cboLanguage = "fr-FR" Then Cells(NextRow, 3) = txtTranslation.Text
                        If cboLanguage = "it-IT" Then Cells(NextRow, 4) = txtTranslation.Text
                        If cboLanguage = "de-DE" Then Cells(NextRow, 5) = txtTranslation.Text        
                Unload frmNewTranslation
            End If
        End With
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I don't that this asks a specific question so much as asks us to write some code for you. Can you rephrase please?

Comment: I'm just trying to find out how to do 2b "If txtTitle exists, add txtTranslation to the row with the txtTitle, rather than "NextRow". I am a beginner, and don't really know how to ask this question other than giving the whole context. How else can I ask the question?

Comment: I also removed the question about prompting for overwrite. I will research that elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go about it:

```
Dim rng as Range
Dim FindString as string

FindString = "*" & Trim(txtTitle) & "*" 'this will match any occurance of txtTitle in a target cell

Set rng = Range("A1") 'set starting range cell

While rng.value <> ""

    If rng.Value Like FindString

        'your code to update the current row here

        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)  'offset the cell down one

Wend

'your code to create the new row here. rng will be positioned at the next empty cell
```

Does that help? A short explanation of what is happening (to help you along your way):

First we set a range variable to the topmost cell we want to search from (A1 in this case). Then we enter a loop: if checks to see if the value of `rng` matches the `FindString` and, if so, you can put your code in there to do whatever needs to be done when a match is found. **If no match is found in that row** the `If` block doesn't execute, and `rng` gets set to the cell below it (dropping us down one), and the loop repeats. The loop will run until the **first blank cell is found**, so it assumes that there are no blanks in the column. At the moment a blank cell is found, the loop ends and the code continues. However, `rng` is set to the blank cell, so you could create a new row like so:

```
rng.value = 'whatever
rng.offset(0, 1).value = 'next column whatever
rng.offset(0, 2).value = 'third column whatever
```

and so on.